# Failing SonarQube analysis on .NET Core 3.1 project

Tags: c#, .net-core, sonarqube-scan

I am running `sonarqube:latest` in a Docker container locally on my development machine to get some stuff working.

I’m trying to analyze a C# project that runs on .NET Core 3.1. Looking at [this page](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-msbuild/) I assumed I could use the .NET Core Global Tool to scan it but that gives me the following error while running the end step:

*WARN: Your project contains C# files which cannot be analyzed with the scanner you are using. To analyze C# or VB.NET, you must use the SonarScanner for .NET 5.x or higher, see https://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/install-configure-scanner-msbuild.html*

This also happens when I try to use .NET 5 `dotnet <path to SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll>` etc. It does nicely scan all the TypeScript and CSS stuff that’s in my project but in the end there are no C# results in SonarQube.

Any idea what I’m doing wrong?

### Update

After doing some debugging it comes down to this:

```
<Target Name="ChangeAliasesOfReactiveExtensions" BeforeTargets="FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences;ResolveReferences">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ReferencePath Condition="'%(FileName)' == 'System.Interactive.Async'">
      <Aliases>ix</Aliases>
    </ReferencePath>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

We are doing this because we're still using an early Entity Framework version.

I assume we get the error because the analyzer stumbles upon duplicate types.

Is there any way to configure SonarQube so this is not an issue?

## UPDATE 2

Apparently the file causing all the problems is `Directory.Build.targets`:

```
<Project>
    <Target Name="ChangeAliasesOfReactiveExtensions" BeforeTargets="FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences;ResolveReferences">
      <ItemGroup>
        <ReferencePath Condition="'%(FileName)' == 'System.Interactive.Async'">
          <Aliases>ix</Aliases>
        </ReferencePath>
      </ItemGroup>
    </Target>

    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(IntermediateOutputPath)' != '' ">
        <ErrorLog>$(IntermediateOutputPath)\csc_diagnostics.json</ErrorLog>
<RazorCompilationErrorLog>$(IntermediateOutputPath)\csc_razor_diagnostics.json</RazorCompilationErrorLog>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Commenting out the content of this file or removing it fixes the SonarQube analysis warning and shows the C# files in SonarQube.

I can reproduce this by creating a new C# project (`dotnet new console`) and creating a file `Directory.Build.targets` with the above content.

Comment: Hi, how do you build your project? Do you do build it with `/t:Rebuild` target between scanner `begin` and `end` step?

Comment: I run `dotnet build`. Tried adding `/t:Rebuild` but still the same error message.

Comment: I've tried running the scanner on a brand new console application configured for .NET Core 3.1 and that works. So it's something my project that makes it fail but I have no idea how to debug this.

Comment: Are you building an SLN or project files? If SLN make sure your project files all have `<ProjectGuid>` properties that match their values in the SLN

Comment: This seems like the Roslyn analyzers were not embedded into the build. Try `dotnet build /v:d` and search for `Sonar` to look for clues. You should see `csc.exe` task somewhere, you can verify if `/analyzers:..path-to-your-temp...\SonarAnalyzer.CSharp.dll` is present (among hundreds of `/reference:...` args). Is there some unusual magic in your targets files?

Comment: The `<Aliases>ix</Aliases>` should not fail the analysis and should not prevent the analyzers from being embedded.

Comment: It's a solution with many projects. I've tested with the smallest one and that one starts working once I remove the `Aliases` setting. If I analyze the complete solution it still reports the error that no C# code can be found. I'll try the verbose flag and see if that shows what's happening

Comment: What version of scanner do you have? Did you set `RunAnalyzers`/`RunAnalyzersDuringBuild` in your project file/targets file?

Comment: I'm using the latest dotnet global tool scanner. I do have RunAnalyzersDuringBuild  set to true. Woudl that be an issue?

Comment: `RunAnalyzersDuringBuild=true` is fine. `false` would require latest scanner 5.2, but I assume you have that one

Comment: I tried the `Aliases` target and it doesn't break the analysis. build with `/v:d` and inspection of `csc.exe` arguments is the next thing to do, as mentioned above.

Comment: @PavlinII I've added an update to the question. Do you know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue with the Update 2. Changing `Alias` doesn't have any effect on the scenario, it's only the `ErrorLog` that makes the difference.

As seen in `.sonarqube\bin\targets\SonarQube.Integration.targets`: SonarScanner sets `ErrorLog` to collect results of the analysis when it's empty. And it doesn't pick it up when it's explicitly set. I'm not sure exactly why is that.

To fix your scenario, update your `Build.Directory.targets` file to set Sonar properties as well like this:

```
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(IntermediateOutputPath)' != '' ">
        <ErrorLog>$(IntermediateOutputPath)\csc_diagnostics.json</ErrorLog>
        <RazorCompilationErrorLog>$(IntermediateOutputPath)\csc_razor_diagnostics.json</RazorCompilationErrorLog>
        <SonarCompileErrorLog>$(ErrorLog)</SonarCompileErrorLog>
        <RazorSonarCompileErrorLog>$(RazorCompilationErrorLog)</RazorSonarCompileErrorLog>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

or remove the explicit values for `ErrorLog` and `RazorCompilationErrorLog`. Json reports will be at these paths:

```
Roslyn: $(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName).RoslynCA.json
Razor: $(TargetDir)$(TargetName)$(RazorTargetNameSuffix)$(TargetExt).RoslynCA.json
```

Comment: I find it strange that Alias has no consequences for your scan. If I leave it enabled, I get the error as stated above.

Thanks for the insights in the ErrorLog!